# Issues in Javascript with Async and Await, cannot get the function to wait for the first function to be completed

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, synchronous

Im new to javascript and Im having an issue with Async and Await. To my understanding the async function will wait for the await function to be completed before running. I dont know if my function is written correctly but Ive tried passing no argument to the await function along with many different variations. unfortunately the logout function runs before the setStatus function is done running. Any help or direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
function getConfirmationToSaveAndExit() {
               var retVal = confirm("Are you sure you would like to Save Item & Logout?");
               if( retVal == true ) {
                      setStatus('Incomplete');
                      logout();
                      return true;
               } else {
                  console.log("user does not want to continue");
                  return false;
               }
            }

function setStatus(status){
    document.getElementById('filledStatus').value=status;
    showLoader();
}

async function logout(){
    await setStatus('Incomplete');
        window.location.href="/logout";
}
```

Comment: In order to use await, calling function must return promise. In your case, setStatus should return promise, to be said.

Comment: So something like this

'function setStatus(status){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        document.getElementById('filledStatus').value=status;
        showLoader().then(logout);

        const error= false;
        if(!error) {
            resolve();
        } else {
            reject('Error: Something went wrong');
        }
    });

}'

Comment: That looks ok, otherwise you can just define setStatus as async function, which converts it to a promise. ( async function setStatus ... everything else can remain as is )

Answer (score 0):

`setStatus(<args>) {...}` function should be an `async` function or should return a `Promise` or a function invocation which returns a `Promise` as well. To be more precise you can even await on an async function without explicitly returning from it. e.g.:

```js
async testFunc() {
  console.log('But, all things being equal, I would rather be in Philadelphia.');
}
```

This function implicitly returns `undefined` wrapped into a `Promise` so you can `await` on it.